# How to get the class type of a calling class in a method call in a different referenced project

Tags: vb.net

My solution is called "PlasmaBlueTooth_Soln" and there are many projects included in the solution.

One of the projects is called "PlasmaBluetooth" and contains many classes and a module and is the startup project for the application 
(The module "startUpModule" contains the `Main` sub that starts the application.).
I have a class `MainFormTestClass` in the "PlasmaBluetooth" 
that inherits a windows form `MainForm`.
I created many UserControls in separate projects that are used in the `MainFormTestClass` by instantiating a variable in `MainFormTestClass`, as the userControl in the separate projects then adding the instantiated control to the `MainForm` window controls.
The UserControl projects are referenced in the "PlasmaBluetooth" project. I have a method `PerformAction` in `MainFormTestClass` that calls a method 
`UserControlAction` in a usercontrol class with an argument of `Me`.
I would like to use the `MainFormTestClass` Type in the method
`UserControlAction(byref MeData as MainFormTestClass)` However, the `MainFormTestClass` Type is not defined in the userControl project.

How do I get the `MainFormTestClass` Type in the UserControl project ?

Comment: How you are going to use provided instance of `MainFormTestClass` in user controls? Because instead of giving whole instance you can pass only data or actions you will use, and don't forget about `Control.Parent` property. Still it looks like XY problem, so elaborating more on why you need to pass instance of form will help us to help you ;)

Comment: The "MainFormTestClass" Form is used for several user interfaces.  I add different user controls to the form according to the applicable user interface for a particular piece of equipment we build (I.E. Automated welder, automated Plasma machine, etc.  I use the compiler #IF statement  to  instantiate the applicable User controls for the current machine application. By passing the whole instant I can decide what data to use in the compile User control library thus keeping application specific methods out of the "MainFormTestClass"

Comment: Then pass only data not a form.

Comment: I believe the Form is irrelevant in this case and is only part of the class because it is inherited..  I do not want to decide what data to pass in "MainFormClass".  I am able to use the data in the usercontrol method but because "ME" is sent I have to use Ctype on any data being used

Comment: What I meant is: `UserControlAction(data As SomeSharedType)`. That mean that you need to have shared type in a third project, which both `PlasmaBluetooth` and `UserControls` project reference.

Comment: 1. Add a third project such as "MainFormTypeLibary" to the solution

Comment: I added a class "typeClass" to the 3rd project library which has the shared variable "SomeSharedType" as object.  I instantiated the  "SomeSharedType" in the "MainFormTestClass as Me.GetType.  I referenced the 3rd project in both PlasmaBluetooth and UserControls.  The UserControlAction(data as "SomeSharedType is not defined. Did I do this correct?